# Tag Deletion Request

Tags: support, retag-request

Was moving too fast and create a tag with a typo on accident.

Please delete the tag [mimedefant](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/mimedefant) as it is not needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it has no questions, it will be deleted by the community bot in due time.

Just have to wait. Not a big deal.

Comment: I'm off to make a question with that tag now... :evilgrin: